# I can't exit the program, just closing the window pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i Make program to show Message and after sometime change the Message but If you close the program, it does not close only close window , Please help how to Close All Codes

This Code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui
from threading import Timer
class s:
    def UI(self, window):
        window.setFixedHeight(500)
        window.setFixedWidth(600)
        self.Label = QLabel(window)
        self.Label.setGeometry(0, 0, 600, 500)
        self.Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Label.setStyleSheet('font-size:100px')
        def mone():
            self.Label.setText('Hello')
            Tim = Timer(3, mtwo)
            Tim.start()
        def mtwo():
            Tim = Timer(3, mthree)
            self.Label.setText('World')
            Tim.start()
        def mthree():
            Tim = Timer(1, mfour)
            self.Label.setText('To')
            Tim.start()
        def mfour():
            Tim = Timer(1.5, mfive)
            self.Label.setText('My')
            Tim.start()
        def mfive():
            Tim = Timer(10, mone)
            self.Label.setText('Program')
            Tim.start()

        mone()
    def pd(self):
        print('d')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QMainWindow()
    sd = s()
    sd.UI(form)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a `QtCore.QTimer` instead of a `threading.Timer`, e.g. (note that the time interval in `QTimer` is in ms)

```
def mone():
    self.Label.setText('Hello')
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, mtwo)
def mtwo():
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, mthree)
    self.Label.setText('World')
def mthree():
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, mfour)
    self.Label.setText('To')
def mfour():
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1500, mfive)
    self.Label.setText('My')
def mfive():
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, mone)
    self.Label.setText('Program')
```

Comment: it's Work, but not reload i mean i need reload every time Until the program is stopped running

Comment: What do you mean with reload?

Comment: Have you replaced the timers in the other functions as well? edit: For completeness I've added the updated versions of `mtwo` to `mfive` to my answer.

Comment: it's working , Thanks a lot but There was an error because of me